# Need to inject title in span element from csv file matching id attribute of span element with IH_No in csv file

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**Need to inject title in span element from csv file matching id attribute of span element with IH_No in csv file.**
**Once HTML span element id attribute matches with IH_No in csv file then corresponding IH_Title value in csv should be injected in span element**

**Need your help.**

**Note: This is just chunk of the original csv file moreover the numbers will be 100K approx, So need a solution without having to use multiple conditions for IH_NO in csv.**

**I tried the below XSL but somehow I could not get the logic right. I tried lot of different things moreover I could not understand how to fetch values from csv. This xsl may not be completely relevant.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="inject" select="tokenize(unparsed-text('test.csv'), '\n,>')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="document($inject)/xsl:template/@match"/>
    <xsl:variable name="valuet" select="($inject)/title"/>

    <xsl:template match="xhtml:div/xhtml:h1[@class = 'title']/xhtml:span/@id">
        <xsl:text>Test1</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$valuet"/>
        <xsl:if test="xhtml:h1[@class = 'title' and fn:substring(span/@id, 4) = tokenize($value, ',')[1]]">            
            <xsl:value-of select="$valuet"/>            
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***Current HTML structure***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003034"></span>
            </h1>
         </div>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003052"></span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003058"></span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

***Expected HTML structure***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003034">replace Hydraulic pump, replace</span>
            </h1>
         </div>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003052">replace;Hydraulic pump, replace</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003058">replace;Hydraulic pump, replace</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Filename for csv is test.csv, Need to import this csv file in xsl and match the values with span element and fetch the IH_Title values in span element.**

```
"IH_NO";"IH_TITLE";
"8000003034";replace;Coolant pump, replace;
"8000003052";replace;Fuel pump, replace;
"8000003058";replace;Hydraulic pump, replace;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand.

Assuming that the HTML document is the input to the XSL transformation, you can get a result very close to the one you show by using:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="title" match="IH_TITLE" use="@IH_NO" />

<xsl:variable name="titles">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('test.csv'), '\n')">
        <IH_TITLE IH_NO="{translate(substring-before(., ';'), '&quot;', '')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ';')" />
        </IH_TITLE>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[@class='ih']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('title', substring-after(@id, 'ih-'), $titles)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I did not bother removing the trailing semicolon but it should be simple enough.

---

***Added explanation:***

Inside the `$titles` variable, the .csv file is tokenized to individual lines and a `IH_TITLE` element is created for each line. The first part of the line is used to populate the `IH_NO` attribute (after stripping the quotes), and the rest becomes the content of the element. In the given example, the contents of the variable are:

```
 <IH_TITLE IH_NO="IH_NO">"IH_TITLE";</IH_TITLE>
 <IH_TITLE IH_NO="8000003034">replace;Coolant pump, replace;</IH_TITLE>
 <IH_TITLE IH_NO="8000003052">replace;Fuel pump, replace;</IH_TITLE>
 <IH_TITLE IH_NO="8000003058">replace;Hydraulic pump, replace;</IH_TITLE>
```

This is a well-formed XML fragment that can be interrogated using the `key()` function to return the value of the supplied key.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me, However for my understanding, could you please explain this <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('test.csv'), '\n')">
        <IH_TITLE IH_NO="{translate(substring-before(., ';'), '&quot;', '')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ';')" />
        </IH_TITLE>
    </xsl:for-each>

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's a great explanation! I have one quick question question. How about the input is like:

"IH_NO";"OP_NO";"IH_TITLE";"OP_ID"
"8000003034";"26202-2";replace;Coolant pump, replace;"26202"
"8000003052";"26202-3";replace;Fuel pump, replace;"26203"
"8000003058";"26202-4";replace;Hydraulic pump, replace;"26204"

I have used the below condition for the above input but it did not work:

<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ';')[2]" />

Comment: I have added a new input file in the question for reference for my previous comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question with your new problem (which seems to be only about converting the .cvs to a workable XML).

Comment: As you suggested I created a new question on top of this question, I just added my problem. Sorry if it looks the same, just wanted to give entire gist of the question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75469325/fetching-the-correct-value-of-ih-title-from-csv-file-and-inject-in-span-element

Thanks in advance.