# Fetching the correct value of IH_TITLE from csv file and inject in span element

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**Need to inject title in span element from csv file matching id attribute of span element with IH_No in csv file. Once HTML span element id attribute matches with IH_No in csv file then corresponding IH_Title value in csv should be injected in span element**

**I have got the partial solution it just that I am not able to fetch just the IH_TITLE value in span element instead the whole row is getting fetched.**

**Note: This is just chunk of the original csv file moreover the numbers will be 100K approx, So need a solution without having to use multiple conditions for IH_NO in csv.**

**The below XSl is working partially, when input the input has just IH_NO and IH_TITLE, However its is not working if it has multiple columns in csv file.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="title" match="IH_TITLE" use="@IH_NO" />

<xsl:variable name="titles">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('test.csv'), '\n')">
        <IH_TITLE IH_NO="{translate(substring-before(., ';'), '&quot;', '')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ';')[2]" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
                    substring-after ( substring-after (.,  ';'),  ';')
                    , ';')"/>
        </IH_TITLE>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[@class='ih']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('title', substring-after(@id, 'ih-'), $titles)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current HTML structure**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003034"></span>
            </h1>
         </div>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003052"></span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003058"></span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

**Expected HTML structure**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003034">replace Hydraulic pump, replace</span>
            </h1>
         </div>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003052">replace;Hydraulic pump, replace</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter">            
            <h1 class="title">
                <span class="ih" id="ih-8000003058">replace;Hydraulic pump, replace</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Filename for csv is test.csv, Need to import this csv file in xsl and match the values with span element and fetch the IH_Title values in span element.**

```
"IH_NO";"OP_NO";"IH_TITLE";"OP_ID"
"8000003034";"26202-2";replace;Coolant pump, replace;"26202"
"8000003052";"26202-3";replace;Fuel pump, replace;"26203"
"8000003058";"26202-4";replace;Hydraulic pump, replace;"26204"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the definition of the `titles` variable to:

```
<xsl:variable name="titles">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('test.csv'), '\n')">
        <xsl:variable name="cells" select="tokenize(., ';')" />
        <IH_TITLE IH_NO="{translate($cells[1], '&quot;', '')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$cells[3], $cells[4]" separator=";"/>
        </IH_TITLE>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Is there a way to check the duplicate occurrence's of IH_NO and respective IH_TITLE and If the same IH_NO occurred multiple times keep the first instance and ignore the duplicate instance? Thanks in advance

I tried this <xsl:variable name="cells" select="IH_TITLE[count(key('title', @IH_NO)[1]|.)=1]" />

It did not work.

Comment: You can [group](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) the titles by their IH_NO and output only the first item in each group. If you can't make this work, post a new question and show an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: Come to think of it, you could do something simpler: since the key fetches only titles with the same `IH_NO`, you could just change the calling instruction to: `<xsl:value-of select="key('title', substring-after(@id, 'ih-'), $titles)[1]" />`.

Comment: Thanks this is a pretty good solution to the problem.